# Hey i am trying to split a string , but I have a problem with regex with the parentheses

Tags: java

I need to split the following string but' I did't know how to the that because i had problem with {}

```
[{"parameter":"value"," parameter ": value," parameter ": value," parameter ": value," parameter ":" value "," parameter ":" value "} ,{new user same parmeters}]
```

I need to itrate this string and extract the parameteres from evrey user, between useres there is a ","

Comment: That looks like json so then the best solution is to parse/decode it as json

Comment: Ironically enough @JoakimDanielson this is the exact same XY problem posed in [What is an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/571975)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is best to first have a look at json Serializers/Deserializers because that will result in less confusing code than using Regex for this.
For example have a look at: https://howtodoinjava.com/gson/gson-serialize-deserialize-json/

Example Code for serialisation with Gson:

```
User user = new User(1L, "lokesh", "gupta",
  LocalDate.of(1999, Month.JANUARY, 1), new Department(2, "IT", true));

Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
  .setPrettyPrinting()
  .registerTypeAdapter(LocalDate.class, new LocalDateAdapter())
  .create();

String jsonString = gson.toJson(user);
```

Example Code for deserialization with Gson:

```
String jsonString = """
      {  
        "id": 1,
        "firstName": "lokesh",
        "lastName": "gupta",
        "dateOfbirth": "1999-01-01",
        "department": {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "IT",
          "active": true
        }
      }""";
    
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
      .registerTypeAdapter(LocalDate.class, new LocalDateAdapter())
      .create();

User user = gson.fromJson(jsonString, User.class);
```